# Trouble with python 3 and spyder 2.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to install spyder2.3+python 3 on Ubuntu 12.04.

First, I made the mistake of using `sudo apt-get install spyder`, which installed a version of spyder which didn't work with python 3. So I decided to use pip.

After some effort, I managed to install spyder using

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade spyder
```

and it installed successfully. However, using the command `spyder` doesn't bring up anything because it seems the file `/usr/local/bin/spyder` got nuked, and I am not exactly sure where spyder lives, as in what directory, so I can run it.

Would appreciate some help in where this successfully installed spyder is.

Answer (score 0):

run this command:

```
find / -name spyder
```

and it will return all files with the word "spyder" on your system

Comment: Upon running the pip install command again, it says the requirement is already up to date, and points to files in use/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages. I just don't know how to open up the IDE!

Comment: at my place (using newest ubuntu-mate) spyder is in Applications/Programming menu. Also is startable with simple spyder via cli